# Why use an anonymous function as a variable?

Tags: php

Im trying to wrap my head around some basic MVC OOP coding concepts.

Consider the following.

```
private $notfound
public function __construct(){
        $this->notFound = function($url){
            echo "404 - $url was not found!";
        };
    }
```

- `$this->notfound = function($url)` So the way Ive been taught is that a function should start with the reserved keyword `function name(params)` In the statment `$this->notfound = function($url)`obviously there is no name after function...Im pretty sure I get the gist of the code but for readability sake would like to understand it a bit deeper. **Why use a function after** `$this->notFound`...? Why cant it be something like `$this->notFound = $var[$url]`
- Usually the closing parenthesis of `If`, Functions etc does not require a semicolon `;` Why do I get an error when I omit the `;` for the closing parenthesis for the statment $this->notFound = function{};`

Thanks

Comment: It's not an OOP concept, but an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), a function defined inline that can be assigned to a variable to call later

Comment: It's an anonymous function which is then assigned to a variable. I think this code was written by a JavaScript developer.

Comment: Please check the linked question and report back if that's not your doubt (I'm afraid I can't suggest a duplicate link without automatically closing the question).

Comment: All good explained it nicely

Comment: As for the trailing semi-colon, it's because the code preceding the block `function() {...}` is `$this->notfound = ...` which is a variable assignment operation. The code block `function() {...}` is the value, and due to it being a variable assignment it requires a semi-colon to mark the end of the statement.